# FindException in connecting with Mysql database

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm using ubuntu system, and using Mysql 8.0. I trying to connect database with jdbc class but having an error,although I added the mysql-connector.jar file,

The error I mentioned below,
-->**Error occurred during initialization of boot layer**

> java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /home/surya/eclipse-workspace/Advancedjava/bin
> Caused by: **java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException:**
> mysql_conntn.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `module-info.java` in your project making it a modular Java project. However, you also have a class (`mysql_conntn`) in the default (unnamed) package, and this is not allowed in a modular project.

Either you need to make your project non-modular by removing `module-info.java`, or you need to move the class `mysql_conntn` to a named package.